# Updates doesn't take affect in django orm, Is there something wrong in my code?

Tags: django, orm, django-2.1

I need to update multiple rows in a `url_field` in one of my models, each `product_id` has its own corresponding new values to be loading. What's wrong with my code? No errors are returned.

```
idlist= ["",""]
url = ["https://www.sample.com","https://www.sample2.com"]
i = 0


while i < len(item_idlist):
Model.objects.filter(item_id=idlist[i].update(product_url=url[i]))
i += 1
```

I expect that every iterations will update my data inside the model.

Comment: is your code literally as above with the indentation? Please make sure you indent your code in the question the same way it's indented in your own project.

Comment: also, you're doing `update()` on `idlist[i]`, not on a filtered queryset.

Comment: And you'd never iterate through a list like that in Python anyway. What's wrong with a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a for loop combined with `zip`:

```
for id, url in zip(idlist, urls):
     m = Model.objects.filter(item_id=id)
     m.update(product_url = url)
```

Comment: No, `filter` will always give a queryset.

Comment: Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Careful with your parentheses. Your `update()` should be after your `filter()`. Not inside.

Are you sure about your idlist ? Because you are filtering with an empty string. So you `filter()` will return nothing, and update nothing.

You can update your data structure like this. Associate an id with a new url into a dictionary.

```
idlist_url = {
 1: "https://www.sample.com",
 2: "https://www.sample2.com"
}

for id, new_url in idlist.items():
    Model.objects.filter(item_id=id).update(product_url=new_url)
```

Comment: change the while into `for item_id in item_idlist: ...`

Comment: Or better, `for item_id, product_url in zip(idlist, url)`